Get whole records from first results of GROUP BY
Here is a sample of my names db table:
id | synonym_id | name        | deprecated
1  | 45         | Amanita     | 0
2  | 45         | Amaniita    | 1
3  | 45         | Amunita     | 1
4  | 31         | Agaricus    | 0
5  | 31         | Agarica     | 1
6  |            | Agartha     | 1

names that share a synonym_id are considered synonymous, and only one from each of these groupings will be not deprecated.
I want to get these results
id | synonym_id | name        | deprecated
1  | 45         | Amanita     | 0
4  | 31         | Agaricus    | 0
6  |            | Agartha     | 1

This is basically like a PostgresQL DISTINCT ON query, and i've tried some suggestions for translating that to MySQL. The following MySQL query works because the minimum of the concatenations ensures a single result per grouping, but it returns strings, not instances.
SELECT MIN(CONCAT(n.deprecated, ',', n.text_name, ',', n.id))
  FROM names n
  GROUP BY IF(synonym_id, synonym_id, -id);

So, I can then split the strings into tuples for the selected Name values, indexed by Name ID.
This accomplishes the same thing, in ActiveRecord:
Name.where(id: subquery_scope.select(:name_id)).
  select((Name[:deprecated].cast('char') + "," +
          Name[:id].cast('char')).minimum.as("cnc")).
  group("IF(synonym_id, synonym_id, -id)")

But I'd like to know how to write a MySQL or AR query to return full Name instances, not concatenated strings or tuples.

This is confusing. Why not just select from names where deprecated = 0

Ah good question. Because if there is a deprecated name with no synonyms, we do want that one. Will revise question, but I think the link to the window function is going to help me. Thanks if you linked to it.
